# Best latex package to render algorithm diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to render some algorithms from the Yamaha FS1-R manual

https://usermanual.wiki/Yamaha/fs1renasa1.2616977742/view

Operators are connected to each others to form an algorithm.
What latex package is best to render such diagram ?

Comment: The most systematic way will be using this tool: https://tikz.dev/

Comment: This is very opinion based question. With which packages for drawing you are (the most) familiar? Use it!

Comment: Every package that provides basic lines, rectangles and text will work here. Certainly TikZ can do this very easily. How you do it in TikZ and which library or third-party package you use will depend on your preferred input syntax. I could see both TikZ-CD/`\matrix` and also Forest with a few adjustments. With LuaLaTeX a `graphdrawing`-powered solution might be possible.

Comment: Or Metapost. Or presumably `pstricks`, but I've never used that. I'm sure David can offer a `picture` solution.